# Error encountered after running 'make' despite finding 'stdio.h' in /usr/include

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, stdio

I've encountered a perplexing issue while compiling a program. Despite having the stdio.h file in /usr/include and compiling with the gcc command without errors, I still encounter the following error when executing the make command:
`fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory`
I've already executed
`sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`
so I'm puzzled as to why this error persists. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

int main() {
    Display *display;
    Window root_window;
    XEvent event;

    // Open display connection
    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (display == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open display connection\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the root window
    root_window = XRootWindow(display, DefaultScreen(display));

    // Listen for mouse button events
    XGrabButton(display, AnyButton, AnyModifier, root_window, True,
                ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask, GrabModeSync, GrabModeAsync,
                None, None);

    printf("Intercepting mouse events...\n");

    // Enter event loop
    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        if (event.type == ButtonPress) {
            printf("Mouse button press event intercepted\n");
            // Add your handling logic here
        } else if (event.type == ButtonRelease) {
            printf("Mouse button release event intercepted\n");
            // Add your handling logic here
        }
    }

    // Close display connection
    XCloseDisplay(display);

    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += program2.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib -lX11"
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks6Ju.png)

I hope to run the 'make' command without encountering any errors.

Comment: Are you building a kernel module here?

Answer (score 0):

> Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

You have a Makefile for building a Linux kernel module. In linux kernel there is no stdio, or X and there is no /usr/include.

I suggest removing the Makefile file.

> I hope to run the 'make' command without encountering any error

Then write a new one for compiling your program. It might look like:

```
program2: program2.c
   gcc ./program2.c -lX11 -o program2
```

Make is a grandpa with 50 years. Consider using a build system, like CMake.